# Cypress_ Clicking an element until you don't find a text value

Tags: loops, text, calendar, cypress, each

I am new to Cypress. There is a functionality to check some events created in a calendar
view.

If I have selected monthly events, then I will be getting 12 events in the calendar
(ie; the count of #table  span.fc-title which has got the text "my event" will be 12.
and each time I need to click the next button in the calendar to go to the next month view).

I am looking to write a method in cypress to verify this functionality.

This is the logic:

Is the text "my event" visible in the current month(do it 12 times){

```
If yes, add 1 to the constant count and click on the next button and navigate to the next month and do the step1
If the text is not found, exit the loop.}
```

I just managed to write the below code. But can anyone please review this and
help me to complete this? I want to loop until it doesn't find the text "my event"

const count=1;
const i = 12;

```
cy.get('#table  span.tc-title')
  .each(($span, i) => {
    const text = Cypress.$($span).text()
    if (text.includes('my event')) {

    const count= count+1
    cy.get('#table button.tc-next-button').click
    
     //if the text is not there I need to exit the loop;
     // I need the value of the count of events too;
      return false;
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution myself..So posting the code structure too for others:

```
  for (let i=0; i < 12; i++){
   const monthCount = parseInt(12 - monthNum); // This is to find the current 
  month and navigate through 
  the remaining months in the current year
for (let i=0; i < monthCount; i++){
  // You can use invoke('text') to get the desired text
  cy.get(#table).find('span-title').invoke('text')
 .then((text) => {
    if (text.includes('My events')) {
  
        cy.get('#table  button.next-button').should('be.visible').click();
        cy.wait(2000);
        cy.log(i);
   }
 })
  }
```

}